# How to troubleshoot a (near total) freeze?

Tags: logs, freeze, troubleshooting

I'm running Gnome on Ubuntu 17.04. I had gnome-terminal in fullscreen, neovim in a tmux session, a background process compiling code, and Chromium running as well, when my system froze up on me. I could move the mouse cursor, barely, with extreme lag, but that's all I could do. I waited several minutes, then tried Ctrl-C, Ctrl-Alt-Delete, Alt-F2, but nothing responded.

Finally, I gave up and held down the power button until the machine shut down.

What I'm wondering is, how can I troubleshoot this? Is there something else I could have tried before forcing a shutdown? Are there logs I can inspect to see what happened? I tried `journalctrl` after rebooting, but it only shows logs from the current boot. I also see some log files in `~/.local/share/xorg/`, but I'm not sure if they're relevant, or what to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following logs can help you debug your system from the last boot:

```
journalctl --boot=-1 | less

tail /var/log/syslog.1
tail /var/log/kern.log.1
tail /var/log/debug.1
tail /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't have logs persisting across boots. I've updated my journald configuration so if it happens again I'll have a better chance of getting insight into the issue.

Comment: Debian keeps logs by default. I assumed Ubuntu did as well. I think you should add your configuration change to the answer.